# PHP+Imagick file not found or path is a directory

Tags: php

I have PHP script to create JPG thumbnails from PDF files. It works untill it encounter *bad* name files with many spaces. (like " aa bb cc     dd.pdf").

Here my simplified code:

```
$cdir = scandir($dir);
foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
{ 
  $cfile = pathinfo($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);    
   if(strtolower($cfile['extension']) == "pdf")
    {
    $im = new imagick($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value[0]); //zero is the first page of the PDF
    $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $im->thumbnailimage(80, 160, true); // width and height
    $im->writeimage('thumbs/'.$cfile['filename'].'.jpg');           
}}
```

I tried everything I knew:

- escaping spaces with \
- using __DIR__
- $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']

I always get or "file not found" or "it's a directory".

I can't rename the PDF files, so how can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try: `$im->writeimage('"thumbs/'.$cfile['filename'].'.jpg"');`

Comment: It doesn't work, I get: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'The path is a directory: /'

Comment: have you tried replacing spaces with underscores? str_replace(' ', '_',  $cfile['filename']) ? I assume the error is in the writeimage line?

Comment: Try `urlencode($filename)`.

Comment: You tried it with the `"`s?  Might try `'`s `$im->writeimage("'thumbs/{$cfile['filename']}.jpg'");` or is the problem in this line `$im = new imagick($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value[0]);`

Comment: the problem is in this line  `$im = new imagick($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value[0]);`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after several try and error, this solve the problem:

```
$value =  __DIR__ . "/". $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value ;
$im = new imagick( $value."[0]" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Windows and for me what worked was installing [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)